# SML set difference

Tags: set, sml, set-intersection, set-difference

I have to implement set union, difference and intersection. However when insert extremely nested sets with tuples it gives me the wrong answer. I have included the code snippet for the functions. Any suggestion I could do to improve my output?

```
val x17 = {1, 2, 8};
val x18 = {{1, 2, 8}, (1, {1, 2, 8})};
val x19 = ({{1, 2, 8}, (1, {1, 2, 8})}, {1, 2, 8});
```

example operations:

```
x20 = {x19} Union x18;
x21 = x20 \ {x17};
x22 = x20 intersection {x17};
```

correct answer:

```
x20 ={{1, 2, 8}, (1, {1, 2, 8}), ({{1, 2, 8}, (1, {1, 2, 8})}, {1, 2, 8})};
x21 ={(1, {1, 2, 8}), ({{1, 2, 8}, (1, {1, 2, 8})}, {1, 2, 8})};
x22 ={{1, 2, 8}};
```

my output:

```
let x20 be {{1,2,8},(1,{1,2,8})};
let x21 be {(1,{1,2,8})};
let x22 be {{1,2,8}};
```

code

```
 datatype expression = SET of expression list | INT of int 
     fun interFunc (SET [],SET b,interSet) = SET (rev interSet)
        | interFunc (SET a,SET [],interSet) = SET (rev interSet)
        | interFunc (SET (h1::t1),SET b,interSet) = if (List.exists (fn x=>x=h1) b) then interFunc(SET t1,SET b,h1::interSet) else interFunc(SET t1,SET b,interSet);

      fun garbage [] = []
        | garbage (h::t) = if (List.exists (fn x=>x=h) t) then h::(garbage t) else (garbage t);

      fun unionFunc (SET [],SET b) = SET (b)
        | unionFunc (SET a,SET []) = SET (a)
        | unionFunc (SET a,SET b) = SET (garbage a@b);


      (* set operation: difference, modified interFunc *)
      fun diffFunc (SET [],SET b,diffSet) = SET (rev diffSet)
        | diffFunc (a,SET [],diffSet) = SET (rev diffSet)
        | diffFunc (SET (h1::t1),SET b,diffSet) = if (List.exists (fn x=>x=h1) b) then diffFunc(SET t1,SET b,diffSet) else diffFunc(SET t1,SET b,h1::diffSet);
```

Answer (score 2):

Offhand, I see a few bugs:

---

```
garbage (h::t) = if (List.exists (fn x=>x=h) t) then h::(garbage t) else (garbage t)
```

It looks like `garbage` is intended to remove duplicates by selecting the last occurrence of each value; for example, given `[1,2,3,2,1,2]`, it should return `[3,1,2]`. However, what it actually does is *discard* the last occurrence of each value, so it would give `[1,2,2]` instead.

---

```
diffFunc (SET (h1::t1),SET b,diffSet) = if (List.exists (fn x=>x=h1) b) then diffFunc(SET t1,SET b,diffSet) else diffFunc(SET t1,SET b,h1::diffSet);
```

If `h1` occurs in `b`, then you need to do something to filter that out of `b`. The above doesn't do that, so in essence it produces the union rather than the symmetric difference.

---

Overall, I recommend reading Eric Lippert's blog post ["How to debug small programs"](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for general advice on debugging your program.